# Need 'picture' on left and 'text' on right on desktop & 'text' on top and 'picture' under the text on mobile

Tags: html, css

Suppose Text = T, Image = M

Desktop order:

```
M T
```

Need mobile order:

```
T

M
```

I need responsive behaviour on desktop and mobile.

```css
.container{width:100%;} 
 #image {width:50%;}
  #content{width:50%;}
   #image {
    float: left !important;
  } 
  #content {  
    float: right !important; 
  }
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .container{width:100%;}
 #image {width:50%}
  #content{width:50%}
  
  #image {
    float: right !important;
  } 
  #content {
    float: left !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="image" class=""> 
<img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/fdec4733b4814d9e958b7f86c25020b5.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="content" class=""> 
    text texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
      texttexttexttexttexttext
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use bootstrap or any other css layout framework?

Comment: can you send me small demo on jsfidde for this,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*OPTION (A.)* **first**. your CSS code was very messy. i cleaned it up a bit. you don't have to write the element every time you want to add a style to it. for example you don't have to write `#image{float:left;}` and then again `#image{ width:50%}` , you can write multiple styles on the same element like so `#image { float:left;width:50%}

**second** IF you can change your HTML structure, move `#content` above `#image` in the HTML. and so, by adding `float:right` the text will stay on the right of the image, and then on mobile , with `width:100%` it will stay on top of the image.

```css
.container{
  floaT:left;
  width:100%;
  } 
 #image {
   width:49%;
   float: left ;
   margin-right:2%;
   }
#image img {
  max-width:100%;
  }
  #content{
  float:right;
  width:49%;
  }


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

#image,#content  {
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  }
 
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div id="content" class=""> 
    text texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
      texttexttexttexttexttext
    </div>
    <div id="image" class=""> 
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    

  </div>
</div>
```

*OPTION (B.)* **with JQ** ( if you can't change the html structure ) : when `$(window).width()` is smaller than `480px` , move `#content` before `#image`

see snippet below or jsfiddle - > **[OPTION B](https://jsfiddle.net/tar4jhzx/)**

```js
$(window).on("resize",function(){
   if($(window).width() < 480) {
   $('#content').insertBefore('#image')
   }
   })
```

```css
.container{
  floaT:left;
  width:100%;
  } 
 #image {
   width:49%;
   float: right ;
   margin-right:2%;
   }
#image img {
  max-width:100%;
}
  #content{
    float:right;
    width:49%;}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

#image,#content  {
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  }
 
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
 
    <div id="image" class=""> 
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
     <div id="content" class=""> 
    text texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
      texttexttexttexttexttext
    </div>
    

  </div>
</div>
```

The solution above uses `$(window).on("resize",function(){` , so it works when you resize the browser. if you don't want that, just remove it and use `$(window).load(function(){` or `$(document).ready(function(){` instead.

Comment: as I can see your text is very close to image..can you please set margin @Mihai T

Comment: added `margin-right:2%` on `#image`  . also added a second solution in case you can't change the HTML structure

Comment: i added margin-right:2% on #image ,but with this image is going slighty under the text on desktop..i want both under same line /level on desktop @Mihali T

Comment: well if you add `margin-right:2%` on `#image` you have to reduce the `width` on both of them. so it sums up to `100%` . use `width:49%` on both `#image` and `#content` . see my code. that's what i've done (`49%+2%+49%=100%`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex property.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-property">
    <div id="image" class="">
      <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/fdec4733b4814d9e958b7f86c25020b5.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="">
      text texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttext
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #image,
    #content {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #content {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .flex-property {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted text on left on desktop with image on right hand side and text on top with picture under image for mobiles format....I already got above answer